# Any way to whitelist or blacklist properties returned from a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Nodes returned in neo4j seem to be special, in that they output as JSON objects, and they don't appear at all if they're null.

An example:
I have a :Person object, and they can have 0 or more :Friend relationships to another :Person.

Let's say that a :Person has the following properties: ID, firstName, lastName, sensitiveThing.

sensitiveThing is a property that might be used by our system, or could be personally accessible to the user themselves, but we don't want to return it to any other user.

If I want a query to give me back data of my friends, and friends of those friends, I might use a query like this

```
MATCH (me:User{ID:777})-[:Friend]-(friend:User)
WITH me, friend
OPTIONAL MATCH (friend)-[:Friend]-(foaf:User)
WHERE me <> foaf
RETURN friend.ID, friend.firstName, friend.lastName, COLLECT(foaf) AS FriendOfAFriend
```

While this lets me nicely bundle up friends of friends as JSON objects within a JSON array, and correctly emits an empty array if a friend doesn't have any other friends besides me, I don't want to return sensitiveThing with this query.

If I try to replace COLLECT(foaf) with a custom object only including fields I care about, like this:

```
COLLECT({ID:(foaf.ID), firstName:(foaf.firstName), lastName:(foaf.lastName)})
```

then I get what I want...until I hit the case where there are no friends of friends. When I was working with nodes before, the object wouldn't even be emitted. But now, I would get something like this returned to me:

```
[{ID: (null), firstName: (null), lastName: (null)}]
```

This is obviously not what I want.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to return a node as before, but whitelist or blacklist properties I want to emit, so I can retain the correct null handling if the node is null (from an optional match)

If I can't have that, then I'd like a way to use a custom object, but not return the object at all if all its fields are null.

Any other workarounds or tips for dealing with optional matches are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a way to whitelist or blacklist properties in the documentation.

However, you can return your custom object by chaining `collect` with `extract`:

```
MATCH (me:User{ID:777})-[:Friend]-(friend:User)
WITH me, friend
OPTIONAL MATCH (friend)-[:Friend]-(foaf:User)
WHERE me <> foaf
WITH friend, collect(foaf) AS FriendOfAFriend
RETURN friend.ID, friend.firstName, friend.lastName,
       extract(foaf in FriendOfAFriend | {ID:(foaf.ID), firstName:(foaf.firstName), lastName:(foaf.lastName)}) AS FriendOfAFriend
```

`collect` will return an empty list if there are no friends, `extract` will keep it that way.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! That's one of the things I haven't gotten around to studying in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`apoc.map.removeKeys`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#map-functions):

```
WITH {p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 3, p4: 4} as node
CALL apoc.map.removeKeys( node, ['p2', 'p4'] ) YIELD value
RETURN value
```